# Florida HOA Director Conflict of interest?

Tags: hoa, conflict-of-interest

A board director performs paid work (jobs) for a service provider (Community Association Manager).  Is this a conflict of interest per [Florida Statutes 718](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2018/718.112)?  If not, is it somehow a COI under [other definitions](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2018/718.3027)?

Florida statutes 718:

> Service providers; conflicts of interest.—An association, which is not
>   a timeshare condominium association, may not employ or contract with
>   any service provider that is owned or operated by a board member or
>   with any person who has a financial relationship with a board member
>   or officer, or a relative within the third degree of consanguinity by
>   blood or marriage of a board member or officer. This paragraph does
>   not apply to a service provider in which a board member or officer, or
>   a relative within the third degree of consanguinity by blood or
>   marriage of a board member or officer, owns less than 1 percent of the
>   equity shares.

Ideally, responses would include yea and nay.

Comment: lol, as a Gainesville resident I now want to know if a particular HOA might have prompted this question...

Comment: Do you know the type of work that director performs in the service provider? E.g. a director, a manager, a salesperson, an accountant, a janitor, a grocer, a baker, a candlestick maker, etc.?

Comment: Assume the director performs maintenance work \ repairs in other communities for the provider.   How does the nature of the work matter?  Please consider providing a response as an answer to the question.